# Set values from jquery array to span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, radio-button

I have html code:

```
<input type='radio' class='at-radio' name='re_widget[0][set_style_for_widget]' value='topbanner' />
<span class='at-radio-label'>topbanner</span>
<input type='radio' class='at-radio' name='re_widget[0][set_style_for_widget]' value='undermenu' />
<span class='at-radio-label'>undermenu</span>
<input type='radio' class='at-radio' name='re_widget[0][set_style_for_widget]' value='topstring' />
<span class='at-radio-label'>topstring</span>
```

How can I replace values in `.at-radio-label` with values from an array like:

```
var fruit = ["111", "222", "333"];
```

Resulting html code should be like:

```
<input type='radio' class='at-radio' name='re_widget[0][set_style_for_widget]' value='topbanner' />
<span class='at-radio-label'>111</span>
<input type='radio' class='at-radio' name='re_widget[0][set_style_for_widget]' value='undermenu' />
<span class='at-radio-label'>222</span>
<input type='radio' class='at-radio' name='re_widget[0][set_style_for_widget]' value='topstring' />
<span class='at-radio-label'>333</span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need to know the position, only set the values in the same order.

```
fruit.forEach(function(value, i) {
    var label = $(".at-radio-label")[i];
    $(label).text(value);
});
```

Comment: And what to do if I need to know position? This code works only for clilds of first parent.

Comment: Post an example of what you need.

Answer (score 4):

Iterate through all `at-radio-label` and replace the content with the array element which has the same index.

```
var fruit = ["111", "222", "333"];

$('.at-radio-label').each(function(i){
    $(this).html(fruit[i]);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this approach:

```
<div id="inputs">
    <input type='radio' class='at-radio' name='re_widget[0][set_style_for_widget]' value='topbanner' /> <span class='at-radio-label'>topbanner</span>
    <input type='radio' class='at-radio' name='re_widget[0][set_style_for_widget]' value='undermenu' /> <span class='at-radio-label'>undermenu</span>
    <input type='radio' class='at-radio' name='re_widget[0][set_style_for_widget]' value='topstring' /> <span class='at-radio-label'>topstring</span>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var fruit = ["111", "222", "333"];
    for ( var i = 0, l = fruit.length; i < l; i++ ) {
        $('#inputs span').eq(i).html(fruit[i]);
    }
</script>
```